# Woocommerce: Show Products in Alphabetic order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ok I know it's might be a silly question or you may think it was asked dozen times. but either I am desperate and missed something or this is some unique problem. Anyway, I need your help.

My client wanted to show her products in an alphabetic way. All was good when I select Default Product Sorting "Custom ordering + Name"
But then something messed up.. and all alphabetic order in "Sort Products" Screen gone. Now they all shown according to their "Order" number.

Is there any way to make products return back to list in an alphabetic order?

I'd do it manually in "Sort Products" but there are about 100 products, and I am not sure when the client will add new products the problem won't come back.

**EDIT**
I've found out that when you are using Default sorting (Custom order + Name) at the beginning all products shown by default in alphabetic order, however once you move one item out of the alphabetic order(e.g one "F" item placed in front of an "A" item) all order messed up, and follows only ordering according to product's order number

Comment: try woocommerce   on your local and there is defoult sorting option in woo commerce alphabetically drop dowm   you can use that

Comment: Thanks Vickey, but not sure what you mean my Local. Default Sorting option that the one I'm using. And it was working fine, until I think we stated moving products around in "Sort Products".

Comment: have you check this    WooCommerce Admin >> Settings >> Catalog >>
When you put the "Default Product Sorting" to default, they will show up in the ranking that you set for each product.

Comment: I have stage version of website when all products where in alphabetic order, I moved one item from the middle of the list to the top of it, and all alphabetic order has gone! Seems that's where all problem.

Comment: have you tried the  code i posted  below

Comment: Just noticed that code. Thanks.. In reply to your previous answer, yes that the option I used.. But client wanted one special item above of all list, so we moved it to the top and after that all order has gone.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Vikas_Gautam's answer and modify it to sort by post title, you would do the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'alphabetical' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['alphabetical'] = __( 'Alphabetical' );
    return $sortby;
}
```

Take a look at the Codex for [WP_Query sort parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
$orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
$args['orderby'] = 'rand';
$args['order'] = '';
$args['meta_key'] = '';
}

return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
$sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
return $sortby;
}
```

Comment: use  the order according to your ease

Comment: you can also   use the plugin  http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-more-sorting/

Comment: Thanks Vickey! I'll try this snipped now. But what arguments I should use for alphabetic sorting? Here I see the code does only "Random" selecting

Comment: I've tried the plugin you suggested. But wordpress warned me about some "notice"(Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated...) And also warned me that plugin has generated a lot of additional content. not sure I understood that. but it works... I just not sure can I trust it :) Recent time I use only premium plugins from codecanyon to decrease any problem

Comment: yes i understand it but wordpress suppert team always notifying this they  always   remove all the defected  item if any  due to security reasion

Comment: if able to   get code  from plugin use that and leave the rest

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @helgatheviking's answer, I tried that and it sorted in (descending) alphabetical order but only if the Alphabetical option was chosen on the drop-down because of the `if ( 'alphabetical' == $orderby_value )` condition.

This is mod which sorts in ascending alphabetical order by default, the differences being the condition `if ('alphabetical' == $orderby_value || 'menu_order' == $orderby_value)` and `$args['order'] = 'ASC'`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'alphabetical' == $orderby_value || 'menu_order' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['alphabetical'] = __( 'Alphabetical' );
    return $sortby;
}
```

The site I was working on has grouped products so I made sure they were alphabetical as well...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 'custom_grouped_children_args' );
function custom_grouped_children_args( $args ){
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$catalog_orderby_options = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
        'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),
   here   ->  'title' => __( 'Sortierung nach Titel, A–Z', 'woocommerce' ),
        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),
        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_clean()` is deprecated, use `wc_clean()` instead.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_clean.html